# Get result from Ajax Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ok, so I'm submitting a form and posting an ajax call as follows:

```
$('#pForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevents default submit
  var form = $(this);
  var post_url = form.attr('action');
  var post_data = form.serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'calc.php',
    data: post_data,
    success: function() {
      // show the result
    }
  });
});
```

This fires off to `calc.php` which performs a quick calculation based on the values in various fields of the form. The end result is a variable `$result` in `calc.php`. How do I access this in my ajax code to display it, just an alert for now is fine...

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: below // show the results comment, write console.log(data); => data is the variable passed in the success function

Comment: thanks for that. i have a few variables in my calc.php file, how does it know which one to use? i'm being thick I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#pForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevents default submit
  var form = $(this); 
  var post_url = form.attr('action'); 
  var post_data = form.serialize();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'calc.php',
      data: post_data,
      success: function(html) {
        $("someplace").html(html);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the results using as below,

```
 success: function(result) {
    // show the result
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  .......
  success: function(data) { // here data holds your response
        // show the result
        alert(data);
  }
});
```

Find more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)